# How to hide data label, and show data label when my mouse point a candle?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplfinance

I want to do something like this picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7mgQ.jpg)

When my mouse point a candle and then show the candle data label.

How can I get it?

I know i can use axes.text() to set data label, but it will alway show on the graph.

Can anyone give me what code should I use?

Please give me some hint.

Thanks!